# Size of files of a scanned directory - PHP

Tags: php

I want to read a directory and get the filesize of each file.
I tried the following code:

```
$downloads = array_slice(scandir("downloads"),2);
$size = array();
foreach($downloads as $value) {
    $size = filesize("downloads/".$value);
    echo($size); //at this point the echo works correctly
}
echo($size); //shows the filesize of the first file
echo($size[1]) //nothing happens
foreach($size as $value) {
    echo($value); //nothing happens
    echo($size); //nothing happens
}
```

That's why I'm quiet confused about the work with arrays and loops right now.
It would also be nice to save the filenames and their corresponding filesizes in one array.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constantly overwriting the `$size` variable, that's why it is not carried on with each `foreach` execution.

You should create a `$size` array and store everything accordingly:

```
$size = array();
foreach ( $downloads as $file ) {
    $size["downloads/".$file] = filesize("downloads/".$file);
}

foreach ( $size as $fname => $fsize) {
    echo "Size of " .$fname. " is " .$fsize. " bytes.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. You're overriding the array in the foreach.

```
foreach($downloads as $value) {
    $size = filesize("downloads/".$value);
    // $size is not an array anymore, just an int
    echo($size); //at this point the echo works correctly
}
```

This should be correct:

```
foreach($downloads as $value) {
    $size[] = filesize("downloads/".$value);
}
```

Full code:

```
$downloads = array_slice(scandir("downloads"),2);
$size = array();

foreach($downloads as $value) {
    $size[] = filesize("downloads/".$value);
}

foreach($size as $value) {
    echo($value).'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the value:

foreach($downloads as $value) {
       $size = filesize("downloads/".$value);
       echo($size); //at this point the echo works correctly
   }

you need to add it to a specific record of 'size' as

```
$size[ $n ] = filesize( ... );
```